# Подскажите, пожалуйста кто-нибудь как исправить: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа

Tags: python

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://stepik.org')
print(r.text)
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
......
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000016DDD9DE550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='stepik.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000016DDD9DE550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='stepik.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000016DDD9DE550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа'))
```

Comment: Из Google Colab всё работает. А просто из браузера сайт вы видите?

Comment: Да, из браузера работает, разные сайты пробовал.

Comment: Попробуйте скрипт от администратора запустить. Может у пользователя, от которого он запускается, нет прав на сеть? Может кстати в фиреволле или в антивирусе запрещено питоновским скриптам лазить в сеть, и это в общем правильно - сейчас есть вирусы на питоне и они любят скачивать всякое из интернета.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, Dr.Web, Файлы и сеть, Брандмауэр, изменить правила для приложений, удаляешь Python.exe.
При следующем запуске файла Dr.Web просит определиться, выбрал "Разрешить приложению все сетевые подключения". Может кому пригодится.